# How can I automatically format C# line indentations like VB.NET

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

When I write something in VB.NET, the IDE automatically formats my line indents perfectly, I don't have to use the tab key at anytime.

In C#, when I needed to edit a line of code, and I perhaps wrecked up the indentation like this...

```
void MyVoid()
{
    if (1==1)
    {
     int iThis = 5; //line with ugly indentation
    }
}
```

..., and I have to correct the indentation manually or use Ctrl AKF to fix it.

In VB.NET, the IDE would fix it automatically when I skip to any other line.

How can I make this as easy as it is in VB.NET?

Comment: There are formatting settings by language in the options window, have you checked these out?  I admit I don't know if these only apply when you force format the document, having myself relied on ReSharper for years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my (commercial) [Continuous Formatting](https://vlasovstudio.com/continuous-formatting/) extension that formats the code as you type.

Answer (score 1):

[Power Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) has an option to automatically format the document when you save. There's also a lighter-weight extension titled [Format document on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave#overview) that should do the same.